# Flask-Uploads will not enforce allowing only .csv files

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-uploads

I'm using Flask, Flask-Bootstrap and Flask-Uploads with Python 3.7.1 to create a very simple application that accepts a csv file containing raw data.

The 'upload' page must allow only .csv files to be uploaded. I have tried to implement the answer given on [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48370533/flask-uploads-define-which-files-are-allowed)

Upload attempts with .csv work as expected, but other file types (eg .jpg) still appear to be accepted. Am I missing something obvious here?

'details.html' simply renders the filename on the page for now.

Python Code:

```
import os  
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads

app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)

# Upload files configuration
csv_file = UploadSet('files', ('csv'))
app.config['UPLOADED_FILES_DEST'] = 'static/uploadstorage'
configure_uploads(app, csv_file)

# index
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

# if csv file, show the data in a table. if not csv file, reload index page
@app.route('/datauploads', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def datauploads():

    if request.method == 'POST' and 'csv_data' in request.files:

        file = request.files['csv_data']
        filename = file.filename
        file.save(os.path.join('static/uploadstorage', filename))
        return render_template('details.html', filename=filename)

    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: one attempt block in client side for example html5 `<input type="file" accept=".csv" />`

Comment: This causes the browser dialog box to default to only showing .csv files, which is nice feature (thanks), but it's still possible for me to upload other file types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are ignoring the upload set when you accept files. You need to use the [`UploadSet.save()` method](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Uploads/#flaskext.uploads.UploadSet.save) for extension checking to kick in.

You also need to pass in a sequence of extensions, currently you pass in a string, add a comma to make it a tuple:

```
csv_file = UploadSet('files', ('csv',))
```

and in your view use:

```
@app.route('/datauploads', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def datauploads():
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'csv_data' in request.files:
        filename = csv_file.save(request.files['csv_data'])
        return render_template('details.html', filename=filename)

    return render_template('index.html')
```

You probably want to catch the `UploadNotAllowed` exception, however, as you'd otherwise get a 500 error:

```
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, UploadNotAllowed
from flask import flash

@app.route('/datauploads', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def datauploads():
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'csv_data' in request.files:
        try:
            filename = csv_file.save(request.files['csv_data'])
            return render_template('details.html', filename=filename)
        except UploadNotAllowed:
            flash('Only CSV files can be uploaded, please correct', 'error')

    return render_template('index.html')
```

I used [message flashing](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/flashing/) (which [Flask-Bootstrap can support directly](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/macros.html#flashed_messages)), but your `index.html` could also be altered to accept an error message.

Comment: Tested this and the app will now prevent different file types from uploading - thank you Martijn. It was necessary to set the Secret Key for this to work.